# How can I solve a diophantine equation x^2-2w^2+2y^2-z^2-constant using SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, equation-solving

I have a triplet, for example `(1806336, 1849600, 93636)` and I need to solve the diophantine equation:

```
x^2-2w^2+2y^2-z^2-constant=0
```

Here the constant is `1806336 + 1849600 - 93636`.

What I tried is:

```
from sympy.solvers.diophantine.diophantine import diop_general_pythagorean
from sympy.abc import x, w, y, z
tuple = [1806336, 1849600, 93636]
s = tuple[0]
t = tuple[1]
u = tuple[2]
diop_general_pythagorean(x**2 - 2*w**2 + 2*y**2 - z**2 - s-t+u)
```

which yields the exception

> "This equation is not yet recognized or else has not been simplified sufficiently to put it in a form recognized by diop_classify()."

Without success, I also tried to avoid using the constant as a variable and wrote directly:

```
diop_general_pythagorean(x**2 - 2*w**2 + 2*y**2 - z**2 - 3562300)
```

The error remains. It would be great to have a chance solving such a diophantine equation directly using a constant which I may express as a variable.

Comment: It doesn't look like `diophantine` can handle this case yet.

Comment: Thank you very much for checking and for your information. If there is an alternative way, I would be greatful for it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [Z3](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm) is an option?

```py
from z3 import Ints, solve

x, y, z, w = Ints('x y z w')
s, t, u = (1806336, 1849600, 93636)
solve(x**2 - 2*w**2 + 2*y**2 - z**2 - s-t+u==0)
```

Gives `[x = -368, w = -865, z = 14, y = 1569]` as one possibility.

Comment: Note that I copied your formula unchanged, although the way you wrote it, you might want  `... - (s-t+u)` instead of `... - s-t+u`.

Comment: Thank you. With your help I even could optimize the task. I am now using `solve(x*x-w*w==s, y*y-w*w==t, z*z-y*y==u, w!=0)`. Here is the [code](https://github.com/Sultanow/pythagorean/blob/main/pythagorean_search2.py). Meanwhile I implemented it in Mathematica as well using `FindInstance[
 x*x - w*w == s*s && y*y - w*w == t*t && w != 0, {w, x, y}, Integers]`, which yields the same results, but drastically faster. The background is described here on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4342283/for-integers-xyz-why-are-these-cases-impossible-for-mengolis-six-square-pr/4343676#4343676)

Comment: So in the MSE system 2 formulation, is this equivalent to seeking a tetrahedron comprised of 3 sides that are right triangles with integer-length sides (Pythagorean triples)?

Answer (score 2):

You already suggest a way to approach this problem in a way that SymPy can help. SymPy can solve `x**2 - y**2 - c` where `c` is a constant. Your problem can be thought of in 3 parts with that form:

```
x**2 - w**2 - s + y**2 + w**2 - t + y**2 - z**2 + u = 0
```

Here is a way it might be done, using a smaller constant, 28, which I will break up into `15 + 8 + 5`. I am going to limit output to positive values since the negatives are redundantly true because of each value being squared.

```
>>> from sympy import diophantine
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> pos = lambda eq: [i for i in diophantine(eq) if all(j>0 for j in i)]
```

Since I broke 28 into 3 terms with the same sign, I will solve `x**2 - y**2 - c` for those 3 values of `c` and look for a solution that fits the pattern:

```
>>> pos(x**2-y**2-15)
[(8, 7), (4, 1)]
>>> pos(x**2-y**2-8)
[(3, 1)]
>>> pos(x**2-y**2-5)
[(3, 2)]
```

So for (x,w),(y,w),(y,z) the points (4,1),(3,1),(3,2) work. So look for a solution between sub-problems for `s` and `t` that have a matching 2nd element and then a solution for `u` that has a first element that match either of the first elements in the `s` and `t` candidates.

Comment: Thank you very much for these insights on how I can use SymPy to approach a solution for this problem.